# How do I deal with this np.where script?

Tags: python, numpy

This is my script:

```
df_smr5['FWCorrect'] = np.where((df_smr5['Firmware E'] == (101122), (101222) | (101320), (19) | (01.10), (01.03) | (1000320), (11000320)), 'OK', 'NOK')
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError

Traceback (most recent call last) 
   <ipython-input-5-52adab99696c> in <module>()
----> 1 df_smr5['FWCorrect'] = np.where((df_smr5['Firmware E'] == (101122), (101222) | (101320), (19) | (01.10), (01.03) | (1000320), (11000320)), 'OK', 'NOK')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'float'
```

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? What did you expect `|` to do?

Comment: what did i do wrong, i want to write the right code. I have a datbase with even more firmware versions, I want to extract the numbers with the correct firmware numbers (101122, 101222,101320, 19, 01.10, 01.03, 1000320, 11000320) thats why I OK and NOK added

Comment: We don't know what you intend with expressions like `(19) | (01.10)`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  The first argument to `np.where` is a condition expression, a boolean value.  `|` is used with `numpy` arrays in the sense of `logical_or` - `or` applied to the elements of boolean arrays.

But you are using it with numbers - integer and floats.  `(19)` is a number, not a tuple.

```
In [61]: (19) | (01.10)                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-212c5dce76e6> in <module>
----> 1 (19) | (01.10)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'float'
In [62]: (101222) | (101320)                                                    
Out[62]: 101358
```

In case you intended to use tuples:

```
In [63]: (101222,) | (101320,)                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-2b5f4e4af1f0> in <module>
----> 1 (101222,) | (101320,)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

`df_smr5['Firmware E'] == (101122)` probably does work, producing a boolean value for each element of the Series, depending on whether the `==` is true or not.